# How to write R data frame to google spreadsheet in specific google drive

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-drive-api

When I write R data frame to google spreadsheet, how can I save sheets with specific name in the specific google drive folder that I create separately for a task?

I programmed currently the below

> write_sheet(data_frame_name, sheet="specific sheet name")
> ✔ Creating new Sheet: jet-basilisk.